# How to delete this 2-dimensional array of pointers? Making a destructor

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

```
malla = new Celula**[n + 2];  
for(int i = 0 ; i < n + 2 ; ++i){  
     malla[i] = new Celula*[m + 2];
     for(int j = 0 ; j < m + 2 ; ++j){
         malla[i][j] = new Celula[m];
     }
}
```

I'm making this code and I allocate memory like this (I want a `n*m` array of pointers to Celula, is okay? Now I need a destructor.

Now I don't know how to access to an object in this array and:

```
malla[i][j].setestado(true);
```

doesn't work.

Comment: *I want a n*m array of pointers to Celula, is okay?* -- No, that's not okay.  You should use `boost::multi_array<Celula, 3>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously consider the advice of @konrad's . If anyhow you want to go with raw array's , you can do :

To deallocate :

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < n + 2 ; ++i)
 {
 for(int j = 0 ; j < m + 2 ; ++j) delete[] malla[i][j] ;
 delete[] malla[i];
 }
 delete[] malla;
```

To access the object :

```
 malla[i][j][_m].setestado(true);
```

Edit :

if `malla[i][j]` is pointer to simply object then destructor/deallocation will look like :

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < n + 2 ; ++i)
 {
 for(int j = 0 ; j < m + 2 ; ++j) delete malla[i][j] ;
 delete[] malla[i];
 }
 delete[] malla;
```

Access object/member can be done like : `(*malla[i][j]).setestado(true);` or `malla[i][j]->setestado(true);`

Comment: @freinn `malla[i][j]` is pointer to first element of array of type `Celula` in your case. your way, you're accessing the first element's member to which `malla[i][j]` points in array. But if you want to access second element (or it's member) of array to which `malla[i][j]` points ? then you'll have to : `malla[i][j][_m].setestado(true);`

Comment: okay sorry but in the constructor was a mistake and really is malla[i][j] = new Celula; but you are right in you understanding, thx!

Answer (score 5):

[Don’t use pointers](https://twitter.com/#!/klmr/status/177173159836008448).

```
std::vector<std::vector<Celula> > malla(n, std::vector<Celula>(m));

// …
malla[1][2].setestado(true);
```

Upshot: one line instead of seven, easier usage, no `delete` needed anywhere.

As an aside, it’s conventional to use English identifiers in code. If nothing else, this has the advantage that people can help you better if they don’t speak the same language as you.

Comment: thank you, but is homework and I have no time to do this :S:S sorry, I will use it in other cases